# repair corrupt cr2 (raw) withouth jpeg prview

Tags: raw, repair, file-recovery

I would really need a way to repair a bunch of cr2 files. The problem is that I'm even able to recover the jpeg preview from the files since I only see a black thumbnail. The files were shot on a wedding. I assume all hardware is fine since the problem occured only with the first bunch of the photos(they were copied to PC and deleted from the card), but all the rest of the photos shot the same day with the same camera and card are just fine. I already tried exiftool, cr2repair, FastStone Image Viewer, Hetman Photo Recovery, and a whole bunch of other software but they mostly only recover deleted files which I don't need. I also tried extracting the jpeg prview but there is only 1 picture (among 300) which has a good jpeg preview) The files seems to be the regular size (around 25MB). I anyone has any idea or a tip for a paid service I'm willing to pay since I'm desparate to get the pictures back.

I know similar question have been already asked but I have tried everything that was mentioned there.

Comment: Have you asked Canon?

Comment: Did you completely fill the card again?  If you didn't, some of the original CR2 files may still be on it.  I also agree with contacting Dave Coffin.    Also, another guy had a similar issue and was able to find help on this site: http://www.neowin.net/forum/topic/1189919-need-help-will-pay-someone-familiar-with-repairing-cr2-files/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dave Coffin, the author of the popular open source DCRAW conversion application (which powers several other RAW converters) has experience of Canon's RAW format, his website states "I do freelance consulting related to dcraw", see:

http://www.cybercom.net/~dcoffin/dcraw/

Additionally on his main page he advertises general data recovery services:

http://www.cybercom.net/~dcoffin/

If anyone can repair your images I'm sure he can, however it wont come cheap.

Comment: Thanks for the tips. I have contacted Dave Coffin but never received any answer. I already gave up on the images. I already checked the source code of the raws and found out where each part of the file begins and it seems that I'm missing a lot of data where the image should begin...